# Find all strings in list which have keywords in it from another list

Tags: python, strings, search

I a list of strings A and a list of keywords B. Now I want to return all strings from list A which have all keywords from B in it as a new list.

```
def string_search(strings, keys):
    res = []
    for s in strings:
        full = True
        for k in keys:
            if not(k in s):
                full = False
                break
        if full == True:
            res.append(s)
    return res
```

In which way could I improve this code? I ask purely out of curiosity, since it works perfectly fine and it is not the bottleneck of my processing chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your general coding style is very readable.
You stick to *PEP8* and your function and the variables are named reasonably.
You could optimize your code by using the built-in functions `filter` and `all`:

```
def string_search(strings, keys):
    return filter(lambda string: all(key in string for key in keys), strings)
```

Also do not use `if var == True:` but `if var:` instead.

Comment: Great Point. Most times I use lists which are iteratively filled and then returned. It seems that using Generator functions generally is better. would you say so? (If yes, then I learned something today. If no, please provide an example)

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the *iterable* in general.
Generators play off especially if you have a lot of items that you only need to read once. I personally tend to use generators when returning iterables from functions and, if I need to read the values multiple times, convert them, using ```list(generator)```.